# scale_x_continuous variable labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm working on a shiny Application that will plot a variable amount of factors across the x axis. These X values are in yearmonth form, (ex. April 2018 = 201804) , so in order plot yearmonth values from different years next to eachother, I assign them "IDs". Using the x_scale_discrete function, I'm able to plot these values the way I'd like. However, xlabels is not properly showing. Please see below

```
dat1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(201711,201712,201801,201802, 1,2,3,4, 
84,92,85,91), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE))
colnames(dat1) = c("yrmonth", "Id", "yVal")


plot1 = ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = Id)) +
        geom_line(aes(y = yVal), size = .85) 
        #scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:nrow(dat1), labels = c("1" = "201711", "2" = "201712", "3" = "201801", "4" = "201802")
```

Comment: I've added the function that I used. This references a datatable that has unique ID's for each specific yearmonth, producing the string listed at the bottom

Comment: That is correct! What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I've added some data and removed the function because I don't believe that will be the way to fix this problem. If you run the code without the scale_x_discrete function it plots exactly how I'd like. Now I'd just like to substitute the yearmonth values on the x axis for the Id's that are currently showing.

Comment: why not this `ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = yrmonth, y = yVal)) +
  geom_line(size = .85)`?

Comment: Running that code makes the plot extremely spread out because of the difference between 201712 and 201801. Which is why I plotted the Id's on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = Id, y = yVal)) +
  geom_line(size = .85) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = dat1$yrmonth)
```

[image]

But this will not show the right distances between the time points.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was making it much more difficult than needed to be. Thank you, Jimbou.